# Why are there "two names" for each GraphQL query/mutation?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am learning GraphQL and one basic point has me puzzled.  I know there is an easy explanation, but I can't find it.  Specifically, from the Apollo documentation (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/essentials/data.html#operation):

> ...it makes sense to name the operation in order to quickly identify
>   operations during debugging or to aggregate similar operations
>   together...Operations can be named by placing an identifier after the
>   query or mutation keyword, as we’ve done with HomeBookListing here:

```
query HomeBookListing {   
     getBooks {
     title   
     } 
 }
```

If `HomeBookListing` is the name of the query, what, then, is `getBooks`?  The name of the resolver?

Similarly, when you pass variables to a query, why are there "two levels" of parameters, like this

```
mutation HomeQuickAddBook($title: String, $author: String = "Anonymous") {
  addBook(title: $title, author: $author) {
    title
  }
}
```

So, would `$title: String, $author: String = "Anonymous"` be the variables passed to the query, and `title: $title, author: $author` variables passed to the resolver?

Of course I can memorise the pattern, but I'm keen to understand, conceptually, what the different pieces are doing here.  Any insights much appreciated!

Comment: It's been a while since I touched graphql, but if memory serves me: "what is getBooks" - name of the resolver, yes. It's not a "second name for the query". You can have `getProducts` next to it. It's simply a "field" in the query.

Comment: Same for mutation: you declare parameter list for the whole operation, then different parts of the operation (addBook / addReview) will use different subsets of the argument list.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev -- Thanks.  I think that's more for the separate 'fields' in the resolvers themselves, on the server, so that you can have `const resolvers= { Query: { getBooks: async() => {....}, getProducts: async() => {...} } }`, for instance.  I think that's what you might be referring to?

Comment: Yep, that indeed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may find it helpful to review [the spec](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018), but what follows is a somewhat shorter explanation:

#### What is an operation?

There are three operations in GraphQL (`query`, `mutation` and `subscription`). Typically, a GraphQL request consists of only one of these three operations, and it forms the root of the request, or the entry point into the rest of the schema.

Each operation has a single object type associated with it. By convention, these types are named `Query`, `Mutation` and `Subscription`, but their naming is functionally irrelevant to your schema. Other than their association with a particular operation, there's nothing special about these object types -- each has a `name`, `description` and `fields` just like any other object type in your schema. Collectively, we call these three types *root operation types*.

In your example, the `query` root type has a *field* called `getBooks`. That field is resolved according to the same rules as any other field in your schema. The only special thing about this field is that it's at the root -- there is no "parent" field that was resolved before it.

Operation names are optional because they do not impact the data returned by the server -- they are there generally for debugging purposes (although some clients and tools use them to provide other features, so it's always good to have them). Specifying at least one field name for your root operation type, however, is necessary, otherwise your operation would not actually do anything (i.e. query the server for the data). Again, these fields are your entry point into the rest of the schema and the starting point for your data graph.

#### Ok, but what about the variables?

According to the spec:

> Variables must be defined at the top of an operation and are in scope throughout the execution of that operation.

While we do not initialize a variable inside the document with a value, we do need to define it by telling GraphQL what the type of the variable it is. This allows GraphQL to then validate the usages of your variables throughout the document. For example, if you define a variable as a `String` and then attempt to use it at an input field that is an `Int`, validation will fail and your request will blow up before it is even executed.

Variables are always defined as part of the operation definition -- they can be used anywhere in the document, though, even multiple times. So there are no "two levels of parameters" here -- one line is simply the definition, the other line is usage.

#### A word on semantics

Even though we have a spec, the language around GraphQL has evolved past the terms outlined inside it. The term "query" has taken on multiple meanings that you may encounter while reviewing various docs and articles. It helps to keep these definitions in mind to avoid getting confused:

- By convention, we name the root operation type associated with the `query` operation the `Query` type
- Informally, the fields on that `Query` (i.e. `getBooks`) that are often referred to as the "queries" of your schema (just like the fields on the `Mutation` type are often called the "mutations" of your schema.
- The complete request string we send to the server, which includes the whole *operation* and any relevant [fragments](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Language.Fragments) is officially called the *document*. However, we often refer to making a request as *querying your server*. This has led to the document itself often being called a query, whether the operation is contains is actually a `query` or a different operation like a `mutation`.

Comment: I'd also like to add that the real world TRPC applications I see don't use ```Query``` at all. They are only using ```Mutation``` for everything. A few different implementations made by various companies.